# How to make log file copy in python?

Tags: python, logging

I want to make log file in python same as in log4j,
meaning as soon the **logger.log** file get's to a size of 1K make a copy of this file and call it **logger(1).log** , In case **logger(1)**,log already exists create **logger(2).log** and of course delete logger.log so next time it will run it will start a clean log.

This is my code but it is good only for first creation of logger file bakup:

```
b = os.path.getsize('logger.log')
print b
if b >= 1000:
  shutil.copy2('logger.log', 'logger(1).log')
```

This is my log.py file so it can be used globally:

```
import os
import logging
from logging.config import fileConfig
from logging import handlers


def setup_custom_logger():
    configFolder = os.getcwd() + os.sep + 'Conf'
    fileConfig(configFolder + os.sep + 'logging_config.ini')
    logger = logging.getLogger()
    # create a file handler
    handler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler('logger.log', maxBytes=1024, encoding="UTF-8")
    handler.doRollover()
    # create a logging format
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
    handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(handler)
    return logger
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to setup a [RotatingFileHandler](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#rotatingfilehandler):

```
import logging
from logging import handlers

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
handler = handlers.RotatingFileHandler('logger.log', maxBytes=1000, backupCount=10, encoding="UTF-8")
handler.doRollover()
logger.addHandler(handler)
```

From the documentation:

> You can use the maxBytes and backupCount values to allow the file to
>   rollover at a predetermined size. When the size is about to be
>   exceeded, the file is closed and a new file is silently opened for
>   output. Rollover occurs whenever the current log file is nearly
>   maxBytes in length.

Comment: I am using this log globally, So I have this module called log.py that I created I tried to add what you suggested but it doesn't seem to affect.I added log.py in the question.

Comment: I don't understand the difficulty you encountered. You just need to use the RotatingFileHandler in place of the FileHandler.

Comment: It's what I did, But looks like class "RotatingFileHandler" is not part of logging.handlers module

Comment: I made a small change, see if it does work for you now. If not, please post a traceback if you have any error, and report also the Python version you are using. I tried with Python 3.4.3 and it does work perfectly.

Comment: Looks better now after importing handlers from logging, there are no errors but a new file is not being created. I'm using Python 2.7.11.The only difference in our code is this:  you use - logger(handler)  and I use - logger.addHandler(handler)

Comment: ok, I got it work using your great answer and help, the only thing I had to add is this : backupCount=10. inside the RotatingFileHandler definition.
Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Glad it worked out. I edited my post with the backupCount keyword argument

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [RotatingFileHandler](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#rotatingfilehandler).

Such a handler can be added by doing something like this:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.addHandler(RotatingFileHandler(filename, maxBytes=1024, backupCount=10))
```

Once the log file reaches this size, a rollover will be done and the old log file will be saved with a name `filename.log.1`, `filename.log.2` etc. till `filename.log.10`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using python logging module with [TimedRotatingFileHandler](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#rotatingfilehandler) handler.